# Unstable Tests Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am starting using Selenium to test my web application.I am using WebDriver API with IEDriverServer.exe. OS -> Windows XP
The main problem is that the tests are not stable.Sometimes they run and sometimes they throw exception.
For example , This is a common place where the tests are unstable.
I have to open a new window and start fulfilling some fields.

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='"+button+"' and @type='button']")).click();//BUTTON THAT OPENS THE NEW WINDOW
                    long initDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    while(driver.getWindowHandles().size() <= numberPopUps){
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                        //15 seconds waiting for the pop-up
                        if((System.currentTimeMillis() - initDate) > 15000){
                            throw new Exception("Timeout to open popup");
                        }
                    }
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
                    if(!winHandle.equals(mWindow)){
                        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                        break;
                    }   
                }
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//WAIT THAT THE PAGE COMPLETELY LOAD       

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='descricaoMov']")));//VERIFY IF THIS INPUT IS ON THE DOM

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='descricaoMov']")).sendKeys("TESTE SELENIUM");`//This is where sometimes the test throws exception saying that is unable to find this element
```

, i want to ask how is this possible ?

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Comment: A few things spring to mind. Your while loop is just duplicating code from the `WebDriverWait`/`FluentWait` - it's designed for 'waiting' in situations like this. Secondly, what version of IE? Thirdly what version of the IE Driver? Also, what errors are you getting? Is it the same one every time? If not, what ones? How often does it fail? Every 2 runs? Every 10 runs? Lastly, have you set your protected mode settings correctly?

Comment: Ie version 8
IE DRiver version 2.39
The error when happens is always the same "The WebElement 'input[@name='descricaoMov''" was not find

I did not configure any protected mode settings because in the IEDriver page specification did not say anything related with windows XP only to superior versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've duplicated your efforts here. The wait.until line does exactly what the next line is doing with exception to the .sendKeys(). Try this:

```
WebElement descriaoMov = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='descricaoMov']")));
descriaoMov.sendKeys("TEST SELENIUM");
```

Also, CSS Selectors are better at finding elements than XPath. I recommend changing the xpath section above to:

```
By.cssSelector("input[name='descriaoMov']")
```

Comment: Keep in mind that just because an element may be located in the DOM, it might not always be able to be interacted with. If your test moves on before you can actually send keys to the element, you will also have the error thrown. You can add in another wait that will wait until the element is visible and not just loaded into the DOM. An alternative is to Thread.Sleep(xx) but I would make it more dynamic.